# SQL Joining on first match only

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I am trying to write an SQL statement that uses an `INNER JOIN` to match bids and offers to each other.

I have a bids table which looks like the following

```
+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| bid_id                  | user_id           | bid_volume                     | bid_price                      |
+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|                     101 |                 1 |                       100.0000 |                       300.0000 |
|                     102 |                 2 |                       200.0000 |                        20.0000 |
|                     103 |                 3 |                        50.0000 |                        40.0000 |
|                     104 |                 4 |                        60.0000 |                       100.0000 |
|                     105 |                 5 |                        75.0000 |                        90.0000 |
+-------------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

I have an offers table which looks like the following

```
+---------------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| offer_id                  | user_id           | offer_volume                     | offer_price                      |
+---------------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|                        91 |                 6 |                          60.0000 |                         100.0000 |
|                        92 |                 7 |                          75.0000 |                          85.0000 |
|                        93 |                 8 |                         100.0000 |                         200.0000 |
|                        94 |                 9 |                          75.0000 |                        1000.0000 |
|                        95 |                10 |                         100.0000 |                         300.0000 |
+---------------------------+-------------------+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

I am trying to match bids to offers, there should be a one to one relationship i.e only one bid can match with one offer. The highest bid should also be the winner in the case if two or more parties are bidding.

A bid should be a winning bid if the `bid_volume` matches the `offer_volume`, the `bid_price >= offer_price` AND it is the highest `bid_price` of all the bids.

I am ordering the bids by `bid_price` high to low so the highest bid is processed first. The problem occurs when one bid matches multiple offers.

Taking the data above bid `101` will satisfy offer `93` and `95`. It should really only match with offer `93` as it is the lower price.

The start of my SQL is below but it is limiting the matches I am really stuck on so there is a one to one relationship of bids to offers.

```
SELECT  
    Bids.user_id AS bidder_user_id,
    Offers.user_id AS dealer_user_id,
    Bids.bid_volume,
    Offers.offer_volume,
    Bids.bid_price, 
    Offers.offer_price
FROM  
    Bids
INNER JOIN 
    Offers
ON
    /* Volume - Volume must be equal*/
    Bids.bid_volume =
    Offers.offer_volume   AND
    /* Price - Bid price greater than or equal to offer price*/ 
    Bids.bid_price  >=
    Offers.offer_price
ORDER BY 
    bid_price DESC;
```

The output of the above is shown below (Notice there are two matches for `bidder_user_id = 1` trying to get only one)

```
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| bidder_user_id | dealer_user_id | bid_volume | offer_volume | bid_price | offer_price |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
|              1 |              8 |   100.0000 |     100.0000 |  300.0000 |    200.0000 |
|              1 |             10 |   100.0000 |     100.0000 |  300.0000 |    300.0000 |
|              4 |              6 |    60.0000 |      60.0000 |  100.0000 |    100.0000 |
|              5 |              7 |    75.0000 |      75.0000 |   90.0000 |     85.0000 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
```

The desired output would be as shown below, so user `1` bid is not matched with two offers but I am not sure how to limit the inner join to only match on first occurrence only.

```
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
| bidder_user_id | dealer_user_id | bid_volume | offer_volume | bid_price | offer_price |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
|              1 |              8 |   100.0000 |     100.0000 |  300.0000 |    200.0000 |
|              4 |              6 |    60.0000 |      60.0000 |  100.0000 |    100.0000 |
|              5 |              7 |    75.0000 |      75.0000 |   90.0000 |     85.0000 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function in the table `Offers` to get the row with the lowest `offer_price` for each `offer_volume` and then join to `Bids`:

```
SELECT  
    b.user_id AS bidder_user_id,
    o.user_id AS dealer_user_id,
    b.bid_volume,
    o.offer_volume,
    b.bid_price, 
    o.offer_price
FROM  Bids b 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY offer_volume ORDER BY offer_price) rn 
  FROM Offers 
) o
ON b.bid_volume = o.offer_volume AND b.bid_price >= o.offer_price
WHERE o.rn = 1
ORDER BY b.bid_price DESC;
```

For previous versions, you could use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  
    b.user_id AS bidder_user_id,
    o.user_id AS dealer_user_id,
    b.bid_volume,
    o.offer_volume,
    b.bid_price, 
    o.offer_price
FROM  Bids b 
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT o1.* FROM Offers o1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Offers o2 
    WHERE o2.offer_volume = o1.offer_volume AND o2.offer_price < o1.offer_price
  )
) o
ON b.bid_volume = o.offer_volume AND b.bid_price >= o.offer_price
ORDER BY b.bid_price DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=252f49488e1967339f2188023ded2673).

Answer (score -1):

> Is this how you did it?

```
SELECT  
    Bids.user_id AS bidder_user_id,
    Offers.user_id AS dealer_user_id,
    Bids.bid_volume,
    Offers.offer_volume,
    Bids.bid_price, 
    Offers.offer_price,
    COUNT(Bids.user_id)
FROM  
    Bids
INNER JOIN 
    Offers
ON
    /* Volume - Volume must be equal*/
    Bids.bid_volume =
    Offers.offer_volume   AND
    /* Price - Bid price greater than or equal to offer price*/ 
    Bids.bid_price  >=
    Offers.offer_price
ORDER BY 
    bid_price DESC
GROUP BY
    Bids.user_id;
```

Comment: No luck, I added the group by before order by, this is what I got `Error Code: 1055. Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Bids.user_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting the same error, this is going to be wrapped in an insert statement which does not have an extra column at the moment no